# ASP.NET MVC Catching and Using Parameter In The View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is the ActionLink in the index view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("€ 50-100", "Filter", new { number1 = 50, number2 = 100 }, null)
```

Here is the filter method in the controller for catching 2 parameters

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Filter(int number1, int number2)
        {          
            var result = db.Gifts.Where(c => c.Price > number1 && c.Price <= number2).ToList();
            return View(result);
        }
```

All works fine, but i want to use the parameter in the filter view forexample;

```
<h3> Choose a gift from the list of € number1 - number2 </h3>
```

How can i do that?

Comment: You should create a ViewModel with properties that represent `result`,  `number1` and `number2`.  You would pass the model to the `Filter` View and access the values from `@Model`

Comment: Thanx @markpsmith. Im a beginner, what i understand is that i should make a class with 2 properties and using these properties in the filter view right? My filter view has got a model already, can i use another model at the same time?

Comment: @AttilaAlan - instead of using 2 models, you can instead create a class comprised off other classes and objects that you need and pass this class/model to your view. This is actually very standard practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New ViewModel that incorporates the filter params and the resultset:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }
    public List<Gifts> GiftList { get; set; }
}
```

Updated action method.  You assign the model properties here and pass the model to the View:

```
public ActionResult Filter(int number1, int number2)
{    
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
       Number1 = number1,
       Number2 = number2,
       GiftList = db.Gifts.Where(c => c.Price > number1 && c.Price <= number2).ToList()
    }      

     return View(model);
}
```

Updated View.  You need to change the model declaration at the top to use the new model:

```
@model MyViewModel
<h3> Choose a gift from the list of € @Model.Number1 - @Model.Number2 </h3>
```

You would iterate over your `Gifts` result set like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.GiftList)
{
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code it looks like you're trying to pass some values form the controller to the view.

You could do this using the ViewBag:
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Filter(int number1, int number2)
{          
    var result = db.Gifts.Where(c => c.Price > number1 && c.Price <= number2).ToList();
    ViewBag.N1 = 50;
    ViewBag.N2 = 100;

    return View();
}
```

View:
    @Html.ActionLink("€ 50-100", "Filter", new { number1 = @ViewBag.N1, number2 = @ViewBag.N2 }, null)

#### Choose a gift from the list of € @ViewBag.N1 - @ViewBag.N2

Or by using a model:

Controller:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public Int32 N1 {get;set;}
    public Int32 N2 {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Filter(int number1, int number2)
{          
    var result = db.Gifts.Where(c => c.Price > number1 && c.Price <= number2).ToList();     
    return View(new MyModel{N1 = 50, N2 = 100});
}
```

View:

```
@model MyModel

@Html.ActionLink("€ 50-100", "Filter", new { number1 = @Model.N1, number2 = @Model.N2 }, null)
<h3> Choose a gift from the list of € @Model.N1 - @Model.N2 </h3>
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question, OP is passing `number1` & `number2` as querystring parameters to the `Filter` method. He then wants to display the parameters in the `Filter` View.

Comment: Yes @markpsmith that is what i would like to do. Thanx.

Comment: @markpsmith You’re right I didn’t look carefully enough at controller code, I just saw that he wants to use the same value in the view more than once.